# Angularfire2: how to retrieve file content from Firebase storage

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am developping a Ionic app using Angulfire2.

I have succeeded uploading files to Firebase.

I found method getDownloadURL to retrieve file URL and this is working fine to display it in HTML pages.

However I cannot find a way to download the file content. I tried to perform an http request like this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "image/png" });
let imageGet = this.http.get(firestorageImageURI, { headers: headers }).subscribe((response) => {
    debugger;
});
```

However I have an CORS error in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxx.appspot.com/o/edls%2Fb2478a2b-48eb-4056-94c8-e83d858cd519%2Fb2478a2b-48eb-4056-94c8-e83d858cd519_b_1603046492694.png?alt=media&token=8ce76185-dd05-451e-919e-49f695145237' from origin 'http://localhost:8101' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I also configued CORS to allow all origins like detailled here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

But it did not change the error.

I also changed the storage rules to:

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service firebase.storage {   
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read, write: if true;
     }   
  } 
}
```

Would anyone know how to download a file from Firebase storage using angularfire2?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was headers which should not be sent querying.